# How can I submit my stripe.js-powered form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a Stripe.js-powered form with validator. Here is my source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
  $('[data-numeric]').payment('restrictNumeric');
  $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
  $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
  $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');

  $.fn.toggleInputError = function(erred) {
    this.parent('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', erred);
    return this;
  };

  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
    $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
    $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
    $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
    $('.cc-brand').text(cardType);

    $('.validation').removeClass('text-danger text-success');
    $('.validation').addClass($('.has-error').length ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success');
  });

});
</script>
```

Here is link to full source: http://pastebin.com/DZhNNGe7
Validator works fine with invalid data but after filling in the form with validated data the form is not actually submitted to get token but I get a green message saying "validation passed". What changes do I need to do to let the form being actually submitted after validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
```

to

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
```

and after correct validation add:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: Please clarify where exactly should I  add $('form').submit(); ? In which line?

Comment: change $('.validation').addClass($('.has-error').length ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'); to if ($('.has-error').length) { $('.validation').addClass('text-danger') } else { $('.validation').addClass('text-success'); $('form').submit() }

Comment: So with both changes in comment above and in first part of your answer about button, the form will be submitted only after validation and I'll get the token?

Comment: I discovered my mistake, your update was correct, the problem is missing stripe-data tags in form fields. It seems stripe requires two `data-stripe="exp-month"` and `data-stripe="exp-year"` but in that form it is asking in one fields separated with / for validation, so I need to add a part in my stripe script to split data of `<input id="cc-exp" type="tel" class="input-lg form-control cc-exp" autocomplete="cc-exp" placeholder="•• / ••" required class="col-md-2">` by / and assign the values to data-stripe="exp-month" and data-stripe="exp-year". Please advice how can I do this in that script?

Comment: For my second question, I created a separate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918956/how-to-split-a-form-data-and-assign-to-another-values-with-jquery